Collapsing and displaying a menu using html php and javascript
I've started using a grid display. As someone with no sight, I find this makes a lot more sense to me, and on first impression, is much more approachable.
Currently, this is my css code:
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'menubtn header '
                         'sidebar content'
                         'footer footer';
  }
  #menubtn {
    grid-area: menubtn;
  }
  #header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: white;
  }
  #sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-color: white;
 }
  #content {
    grid-area: content;
  }
  #footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: white;
  }

As you can see, I've a button in the top left-hand side of the header, and the idea is to click this button to either collapse or display the menu.
Is there a way using JavaScript to resize the content div and close the menu, and to take it back to its original size when the menu is reopened?
Here's some code that didn't quite work:
  echo '<menubtn>';
  echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>';
  echo '</menubtn';

JavaScript:
   <script>
      /* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
      function openNav() {
         
document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = 
"250px";
         
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = 
"250px";
      }

      /* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
      function closeNav() {
         
document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
         
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      }
   </script>

Code overload I know, but I'm trying to provide as much information as I reasonably can.
Update: Thanks to a patient member of this forum, I've changed my approach, it still doesn't work, but I think it's the right way.
In my php script, I've this:
      echo '<div id="menubtn">';
  echo '<button onclick = "menuButton()" > Menu</button>';
  echo '</div>';

My JavaScript looks like this:
   <script>
  const
  menuButton = document.getElementById('menubtn'),
  trueMenu = document.getElementById('true-menu'),
  closeButton = document.getElementById('close-true-menu');

menuButton
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => {
      trueMenu.showModal();
    }
);

closeButton
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
     () => {
      trueMenu.close();
    }
  );
   </script>

It could be my screen reader playing tricks on me, i.e. not recognizing the overlay, but I doubt it.
I've defined the modal dialog thus:
    echo '<dialog id="true-menu">">';
echo '<button id="close-true-menu">Close</button>';
blah blah

    echo '</dialog>';


Seems that echo '</menubtn'; is missing a closing >?

I've corrected this, but still no luck. Thanks for correcting this.

Just to be clear, are you trying to "push" the content to the side and have the menu appear, while keeping the header and footer in their same positions? If so, you might want to look at translate instead of margins. https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/poMoWmj. Alternatively, if you just want something to appear "nearer" to the user, you might want to consider a modern modal, which is represented by the dialog tag: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/gOVOGQB

One thing I'd strongly recommend avoiding is setting CSS values directly in JavaScript, and whenever possible, add/remove/toggle CSS classes (or other attributes) instead. This can make debugging a lot easier.

"As someone with no sight..." - I apologize if this question is rude or too forward, but do you mean this literally, or is this phrasing meant to imply that you would think that someone with a visual impairment would have these beliefs? Specifically I'm asking in relation to "...I find this makes a lot more sense to me, and on first impression, is much more approachable". What part of the HTML (or DOM) as you've presented makes it more approachable for someone with a visual impairment? As a long-term developer who care about accessibility, I'm genuinely curious.

The idea of a grid seems more logical to me. I've no sight at all, but try to imagine a page as a set of cards cut to specific sizes. A grid makes this easier to imagine. In the past, I've used CSS, and it's been a bit hit and miss with sizing etc, and has involved the intervention of someone with sight. I feel I've more control with a grid. I can access the code in the codepens, but it won't allow me to copy it. Having said that, typing it in is, for me, a good plan, as I'll remember it and understand it a lot better. Gratefully...

"Just to be clear, are you trying to "push" the content to the side and have the menu appear, while keeping the header and footer in their same positions?" Yes, such that the content becomes wider, and the menu disappears. Everything then fits when the menu button is pressed.

OK, so I've implemented the code kindly provided in Codepen. However, I'm not clear about how this will work. How will it know which JavaScript function to call. Do I need to call the relevant script from the button? Do I need a $_SESSION flag to say whether the menu is opened or closed, so that I can check which button to display?

@user2305558, thank you for your responses! I supplied two Codepen links, so I'm not certain which you are working with. My personal recommendation and preference is the second one which doesn't "push" anything, but instead uses a native HTML5 <dialog> element which, when activated via showModal(), will have both visual and accessible focus. Personally, I find that when the underlying content moves ("pushes") in response to the menu opening it is distracting, and with recent CSS changes we can finally animate hidden things with the allow-discrete attribute.

I'm anxious to know how both work, and whilst I'll probably end up using the second, based on your opinion that it looks better, I'd just like to fill a hole in my knowledge to find out how the first would be implemented as it might be useful to toggle something in other contexts.

I would generally say that code such as <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()"> is "the old way" of doing things. Not the wrong way, to be clear, just an older style. I think most modern JS event handling is done in one of two ways, either a single handler on the global document and then looking at the target, or individual handlers on elements via document.getElementById() or document.querySelector() or similar. I'm mostly in the latter camp, however there's advantages and disadvantages to both.

You said you can't get to the JS in Codepen, so here's an example of some more modern vanilla JS techniques for event handling. This uses querySelectorAll(), which I prefer because I sometimes have multiple things that I want to perform the same action on, a forEach to iterate over, and then adds an event listener with an anonymous function that toggles a CSS class on something. document.querySelectorAll('[data-role=mobile-menu-activator]').forEach((button) => {button.addEventListener('click', () => {document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('hidden');});});

Chris, I can now access codepen. I created an account which allows me to export the code as a zip file. The problem with my menu is that it depends on the user type, i.e. only certain options appear depending ion the type of user logged in. I've now looked at your second option, and, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to rely on the menu being hard coded rather than dynamic.

You've got a button to activate the menu, the menu itself, and the menu's contents. Are you saying that contents are variable, or that they entire menu might not be available depending on the user? If the latter, the advantage of the querySelector (or getElementById) is that if it doesn't return anything, then you just don't bind an event handler, and you can optionally hide the button.

Sorry, the menu will always be available, but the number of options will change depending on the user's status. I've your two JS functions, and the button shows up fine, but nothing happens when I activate the button. I asume that this is either because my syntax is wrong, but more likely, I'm not calling the function correctly?

@user2305558, I think it might be best if you post a new question with what you are trying, these comments get difficult after a while.

OK, going for your second approach probably means I don't need the sidebar any more?

I was considering "sidebar" and "nav" as separate things, but now I see I was wrong. Ultimately the design is up to you, but some people have the sidebar/nav "visible" at desktop resolutions, and then "hidden" on mobile. So you can use grid for desktop, and then use fixed positioning or a dialog in mobile.

I've gone for your second approach, and edited the post accordingly. Still missing something, but think it'll work as I need it. There may be an error in my syntax.
